# How do I run a maximum of 4 jobs in the background?

Tags: bash

I use bash scripting to make use of multi cores by running C++ programs in the background using the `&` symbol. (I'm a mathematician doing Monte Carlo Simulations).

This way I can run a C++ program in the background many times. For example:

```
for x in $(seq 1 1 100)
do 
./program_name &
done
```

Sometimes `program_name` will run fast, and sometimes it will run slow. This is random and impossible to know in advance. This prompts my question:

**How do I make it, so that at any given time, no more than 4 jobs will be running simultaneously?
Lets suppose 4 jobs are running at the moment. I want it so as soon as one finishes, the next one starts.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On GNU, FreeBSD, and OSX you can use `xargs`:

```
echo {1..100} | xargs -n 1 -P 4 ./program_name
```

Alternatively, you can install and use GNU parallel, which is made for exactly this kind of thing (for 4 jobs rather than 1 job/core, add `-j 4`):

```
parallel --gnu ./program_name ::: {1..100}
```

Answer (score 1):

The other solutions to this post are better than the one I am showing here. But I'd like to document my "less than perfect one" for completition. It doesn't have the ability to add a new job to the queue after one finishes... which is a bad thing because it creates idle time.

But the advantage is that you don't need to install anything. I'm hoping also that this is going to be less bug prone.

```
count=1 # current number of jobs processing
j=4 ## maximum number of jobs

for x in $(seq 1 1 10)
do 
 echo Currently running programe $x
 ## CPP code goes here
 sleep $x &  ## Pretend it takes x seconds to complete

 count=$((count+1))  ## add one to the no. jobs running  

  if [ "$count" -gt "$j" ]; then
  echo "Waiting for jobs to finish"
  wait
  count=1
  fi
done
```

A clearly inefficient method, and I welcome any improvements.

Comment: this solution can be improved using fifo to be asynchronous, for example: `mkfifo fifo ; function process { pid=$(sh -c 'echo $PPID'); echo "$pid started"; while read arg; do echo "$pid processing $arg"; sleep $((arg%4+1)); echo "$pid processed $arg"; done;}; for ((j=0;j<4;j+=1)); do process < fifo & done; seq 1 1 100 > fifo & wait`

Answer (score 0):

```
( #Start a subshell
  N=4 #Specify number of jobs
  for((i=1;i<100;i++)) 
   do [ $((i%N)) = 0 ] && wait #Wait every N jobs
    (sleep 1; echo "$i";)&      #Some task
   done
 wait 
)
```

The logic is pretty simple and it can be turned into a one-liner.
You need a subshel to prevent interference with processes running in the background of the current session that we don't want to wait on.